# Android Studio: Is there a way to change the text shown on an ArrayAdapter?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

Whenever the ArrayAdapter is given everything needed from the database it's creating each button with, I think, the memory location of each bit of the database. I say I think because the structure changes each time I go back and forth a page within the app. I got it working using buttons, but that method prevented me from doing other things, such as editing and erasing from the database due to the button itself not having all the information required because it's a button.
This is what it currently does when I try to use ArrayAdapters :

[image]

And this is what I am trying to have it say instead :
[image]

This is the code used to try to create the ArrayAdapter :

```
    void Testing() {
    DataBaseHelper databaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(View_Products.this);
    List<ProductModel> allProductsFromType = databaseHelper.GetAllProductsFromType(productType);
    ArrayAdapter productArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ProductModel>(View_Products.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allProductsFromType);
    lv_products_added.setAdapter(productArrayAdapter);

    lv_products_added.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Toast.makeText(View_Products.this, "Testing " + allProductsFromType.get(i).GetName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the code for the database :

```
public List<ProductModel> GetAllProductsFromType(String product_type) {
    List<ProductModel> products = new ArrayList<>();
    String queryString = "SELECT * FROM " + PRODUCT_TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCT_TYPE + " LIKE " + '\'' + product_type + '\'';
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);

    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        do {
            int productID = cursor.getInt(0);
            String productType = cursor.getString(1);
            String productName = cursor.getString(2);
            String productBrand = cursor.getString(3);

            ProductModel newProduct = new ProductModel(productID, productName, productBrand, productType);


            products.add(newProduct);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return products;
}
```

Any advice on what I need to do to get the desired result? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter, your issue is **the array adapter creates a view by calling Object#toString() on each data object in the collection**. You could override the toString method or customise as per the link to the List Adapter View guide.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public ArrayList<String> GetSingleProducts(String product_type) {
    List<ProductModel> products = new ArrayList<>();
    String queryString = "SELECT * FROM " + PRODUCT_TABLE + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCT_TYPE + " LIKE " + '\'' + product_type + '\'';
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);

    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        do {
            int productID = cursor.getInt(0);
            String productType = cursor.getString(1);
            String productName = cursor.getString(2);
            String productBrand = cursor.getString(3);
            products.add(productName );
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return products;
}


 

 void Testing() 
{
    DataBaseHelper databaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(View_Products.this);
    ArrayList<String> allProductsFromType = databaseHelper.GetSingleProducts(productType);
    ArrayAdapter productArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(View_Products.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allProductsFromType);
    lv_products_added.setAdapter(productArrayAdapter);

    lv_products_added.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Toast.makeText(View_Products.this, "Testing " + allProductsFromType.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```